# Different behaviours of CInt with blank spaces

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I discovered a strange occurrence with `CInt` and I can't find what's causing it to behave like that.

On one machine, `CInt("1 010 220")` yields "1010220" as an integer.

On another, `CInt("1 010 220")` throws an exception saying "Conversion from string "1 010 220" to type 'Integer' is not valid." (I have since found a workaround in trimming the spaces)

This is executed as a registered component on each environment. If I make a simple console app that just parses a number with spaces, both complete successfully.

The code was compiled on the machine that works, the target Framework is 3.5, Visual Studio 2013. It cannot be recompiled on the other one as Visual Studio is not installed there (controlled testing environment).

What could cause `CInt` to behave differently? Is there a global Framework setting that can affect its behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like it may be a culture difference - perhaps it's working on machines which use " " as a grouping separator?

Comment: Not for nothing, but `Integer.TryParse()` would avoid the issue, no?

Comment: @Plutonix That's how I resolved the one issue that popped up. There are about 200 other cases of `CInt` in the code base, however... I want to know what's ahead.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right on the money. The default user is set to a different language on each machine, and each identity set to the component group has no defined regional settings, so they go to default. The machine where `CInt` works indeed has " " as a grouping separator, the one where it doesn't has a comma instead.

Comment: Listen to master Skeet